# Unable to validate the antiforgery token

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, antiforgerytoken

I was trying to pass antiforgery token to my HTTPPost method in MVC controller from my js file. I am getting the following error:

"Anti-forgery token validation failed : The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present."

When I try to debug the js code and see, I am seeing the token in 'antiForgeryToken' variable. But not sure what's going on. Can someone tell me what wrong am I doing? Here is my code from js file:

```
options.data = function (find) {
                                var antiForgeryToken = $("#forgeryToken").val();
                                fetch('/Options/Students/StudentScore',
                                    {
                                        method: 'POST',
                                        body: JSON.stringify({
                                            find: find,
                                            querystringParams: querystringParams
                                        }),
                                        headers: {
                                            "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
                                            "RequestVerificationToken": antiForgeryToken
                                        } 
                                    })
                                    .then(function (response) { return response.json() })
                                    .then(function (response) {
                                        var mapped = _.map(response.Results,
                                            function(i) {
                                                return {
                                                    DisplayValue: i.text
                                                }
                                            });
                                        return mapped;
                                    })
                                    .catch(function(err) {
                                        debugger;  
                                    });
                            }
```

Here is my action method

```
        [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute]
        public async Task<ActionResult> StudentScore([FromBody] StudentValues request)
        {
            //Implementation
            return JsonNet(sometestval, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Here is my antiforgery class

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public class ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            try
            {
                if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                {
                    ValidateRequestHeader(filterContext.HttpContext.Request);
                }
                else
                {
                    AntiForgery.Validate();
                }
                    
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                throws exception;
            }
        }

        private static void ValidateRequestHeader(HttpRequestBase request)
        {
            var cookieToken = string.Empty;
            var formToken = string.Empty;
            var tokenValue = request.Headers["RequestVerificationToken"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tokenValue))
            {
                var tokens = tokenValue.Split(':');
                if (tokens.Length == 2)
                {
                    cookieToken = tokens[0].Trim();
                    formToken = tokens[1].Trim();
                }
            }

            AntiForgery.Validate(cookieToken, formToken);
        }
    }
```

Comment: As `Willy David Jr` said,you need to get data from $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').If you don't have input which name is `__RequestVerificationToken`,you need to add `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` or `<form method="post"></form>` to your view.

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit this one:

```
var antiForgeryToken = $("#forgeryToken").val();
```

To this one:

```
var antiForgeryToken = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
```

Usually, the AntiForgery token is named **__RequestVerificationToken** and not an ID with **forgeryToken** unless you explicitly renamed that.